# Can Coset of a normal subgroup be closed under conjugation and distinct

Tags: group-theory

Can someone provide an example where N is a normal subgroup of G and aN is closed under conjugation but aN is not the same as N?
I tried proving that this is not possible but now I am convinced that it is.

Comment: $aN$, if different from $N$, is *not*  a subgroup, hence it cannot be said to be ‘normal’.

Comment: In that case I used the wrong word the right question would be is there an aN such that $\forall x  \in aN , \forall g  \in G , gxg^{-1}  \in aN$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $G = F\langle a, b, c\rangle $ to be the free group on three generators $a, b, c$ and take $N$ to be the normal subgroup generated by $c$. So $N$ is the kernel of the unique homomorphism from $G$ to $F\langle x, y\rangle$ that maps $a$ to $x$, $b$ to $y$ and $c$ to $1$. Then $b(aN)b^{-1} = (bab^{-1})(bNb^{-1}) = bab^{-1}N$, so $b(aN)b^{-1} = aN$ iff $a^{-1}bab^{-1} \in N$, iff $x^{-1}yxy^{-1} = 1$ in $F\langle x, y\rangle$ but that is false ($x^{-1}$ and $y$ do not commute in $F\langle x, y\rangle$).